# Open Source Image Gallery app

Tags: php, python, mysql, html, ruby

Can anyone recommend an open source Image Gallery for our website.  No doubt going to be PHP/Python/Ruby based with a MySQL backend if necessary.  It is for a Sailing Club so I am looking for something where certain members can create a new Folder for each day out and all other members can then upload their pictures from that day.

At the moment I have got phpBB working as the message forum on this site.  Actually not quite complete as I am still trying to incorporate that into one of our existing pages rather that have the forum in its own full new page.

Comment: Do you need the gallery to be managed through the phpBB backend (users and admins)? If not, I'm sure a quick Google-Search will help you...

Comment: I think this is off-topic for StackOverflow. I'd recommend it be  migrated to [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Would be nice for both Message Forum and Image Gallery to share same Users and Groups but not absolutely necessary if not possible to do.  Maybe phpBB is overkill for the low quantity messages I am expecting.

Comment: Consider to post your question on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com). Other people [already did so](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=gallery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this in a long long time, but it used to be somewhat decent* back in the days:

http://gallery.menalto.com/

* That is as decent as PHP apps get. IIRC it had required some unsafe PHP settings on the webserver, but they fixed that in later versions. $SearchEngine is your friend for that.

Comment: Michael, any idea if this can actually be incorporated with our own webpage or does it always (like many others) run in its own full page.

Comment: @Nick: As far as I remember it has an option in the settings to embed it within another site. As I said, it's a long time since I last used this, you are better off reading the documentation.

Comment: Michael, unfortunately Gallery still requires php Safe Mode so cannot use that on our existing servers.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.